# Error: org.json.JSONException: No value for description

Tags: android, android-volley

my mainactivity is

```
    package com.blogspot.ajjavaprograms.i_bid;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DividerItemDecoration;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Painting extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mList;
    private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
    private List<Data> data;
    private DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

        @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_painting);
            mList=findViewById(R.id.recyclerview1);
            data=new ArrayList<>();
            adapter=new Data_Adapter(getApplicationContext(),data);
            linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            dividerItemDecoration= new DividerItemDecoration(mList.getContext(),linearLayoutManager.getOrientation());
            mList.setAdapter(adapter);
            mList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            mList.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
            mList.setHasFixedSize(true);
            getData();
            }
            private  void getData()
            {
                final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                progressDialog.show();

                final JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Constants.paint, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                                Data data1 = new Data();
                                if(jsonObject.has("itemname"))
                                data1.setItemname(jsonObject.getString("itemname"));
                                data1.setDescription(jsonObject.getString("description"));
                                data1.setPrice(jsonObject.getString("price"));

                                data.add(data1);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                progressDialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        }
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("Volley", error.toString());
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
                requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
            }
            }
```

the error while running is

> W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for description
>           at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:392) W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getStri

1. List item

ng(JSONObject.java:553)

> ```
>     at com.blogspot.ajjavaprograms.i_bid.Painting$1.onResponse(Painting.java:67)
>     at com.blogspot.ajjavaprograms.i_bid.Painting$1.onResponse(Painting.java:57)
>     at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:90)
>     at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
>     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6762)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
> ```
>
> W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for description
>           at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:392)
>           at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:553) W/System.err:     at
>   com.blogspot.ajjavaprograms.i_bid.Painting$1.onResponse(Painting.java:67)
>           at com.blogspot.ajjavaprograms.i_bid.Painting$1.onResponse(Painting.java:57)
>           at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:90)
>           at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6762)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>       org.json.JSONException: No value for price
>           at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:392) W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:553)
>           at com.blogspot.ajjavaprograms.i_bid.Painting$1.onResponse(Painting.java:68)
>           at com.blogspot.ajjavaprograms.i_bid.Painting$1.onResponse(Painting.java:57)
>           at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:90)
>           at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6762)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>       org.json.JSONException: No value for description
>           at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:392)
>           at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:553)
>           at com.blogspot.ajjavaprograms.i_bid.Painting$1.onResponse(Painting.java:67)
>           at com.blogspot.ajjavaprograms.i_bid.Painting$1.onResponse(Painting.java:57)
>           at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:90)
>           at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6762)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>       org.json.JSONException: No value for description W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:392)
>           at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:553)
>           at com.blogspot.ajjavaprograms.i_bid.Painting$1.onResponse(Painting.java:67)
>           at com.blogspot.ajjavaprograms.i_bid.Painting$1.onResponse(Painting.java:57)
>           at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:90)
>           at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:102)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6762) W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>   Application terminated.

help please!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No value for description means there is no such key available in the current json object. Please try following,

```
   if(jsonObject.has("itemname")){
        data1.setItemname(jsonObject.getString("itemname"));
     } else if(jsonObject.has("descript")){
        data1.setDescription(jsonObject.getString("descript"));
      }else if(jsonObject.has("price")){
        data1.setPrice(jsonObject.getString("price"));
      }
       data.add(data1);
```

Comment: Still no progress after that shows same error While my json is {"datalist":[{"itemname":"painting"},{"type":"painting"},{"descript":"it is a painting"},{"price":"4000"},{"emailid":"jaics.9f9@gmail.com"}]}

Comment: In your JSON string the key is "descript", but in your code the key is "description", thats a mismatch. Updated my answer above, i am trying to help you.